# Ext js 7 cmd Production build failing

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

I have a working test build, I produce by typing:
`sencha app build testing`

it's working without problems, and now I would love to test sencha speed in production stage. But i can't make a build, I tried `sencha app build` but I get a generic error, so I tried to get more debug infos with `sencha -d app build`

But I don't understand the log file, I can't find a missing plugin or something like that.

Can somebody please take a look?
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Masegi/tmp/main/error1.log

I replace my app name with "myapp1", hope that's ok.

This is the generic error I get:

```
[ERR] Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:917)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:922)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:918)
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.SymbolCache.getDefinedMembers(SymbolCache.java:922)
```

While my testing build is working fine:

```
Sencha Cmd v7.3.0.19
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : desktop (testing environment)
[INF] Loading compiler context
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Processing data with ClosureCompressor
[INF] JavaScript input level is NEXT and output level is ES5
[INF] Writing concatenated output to file /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/generatedFiles/desktop/app.js
[INF] merging 863 input resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/desktop/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/desktop/resources
[INF] merging 501 input resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/slicer-temp/bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/slicer-temp/bootstrap.js
[INF] writing sass content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss.tmp
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/generatedFiles/desktop.json
[LOG] Fashion build starting for /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss
[LOG] Fashion build complete for /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss
[LOG] Fashion build completed in 2.673 sec.
[INF] Copying page resources to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/generatedFiles/desktop.json
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/index.php
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/index.php
[INF] 
[INF] ======================================================================
[INF] 
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : phone (testing environment)
[INF] Loading compiler context
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Processing data with ClosureCompressor
[INF] JavaScript input level is NEXT and output level is ES5
[INF] Writing concatenated output to file /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/generatedFiles/phone/app.js
[INF] merging 863 input resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/phone/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/phone/resources
[INF] merging 501 input resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1
[INF] merged 0 resources into /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/slicer-temp/bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/slicer-temp/bootstrap.js
[INF] writing sass content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss.tmp
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/generatedFiles/phone.json
[LOG] Fashion build starting for /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss
[LOG] Fashion build complete for /var/www/myapp1/build/temp/testing/myapp1/sass/myapp1-all.scss
[LOG] Fashion build completed in 2.587 sec.
[INF] Copying page resources to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/generatedFiles/phone.json
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/index.php
[INF] Writing content to /var/www/myapp1/build/testing/myapp1/index.php
```

My java version is:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

My javac version is:
javac 1.8.0_271

Edit 2:

When I enter `sencha ant build` it outputs:

```
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.chart.legend.LegendBase for file Ext.chart.legend.Legend
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.chart.legend.LegendBase
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 3 seconds
```

So it has something to do with charts, but they are working in testing/developement build.

Comment: I added the generic error I get when i build by sencha cmd on my debian 10 with oracle java

Comment: I just realized I'm using 7.0 CE, but my charts version is for 7.3.0, do I need to override anything to make it 7.0 ce compatible? The Legend file is there, so i don't get why it wont find it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After buying the licence, updating to 7.3 and opening a ticket i got a solution:

add "optimize" : false to production/js in app.json and build is working.

```
    "production": {
        "output": {
            "js" : {
                "optimize" : false
            },
          "appCache": {
            "enable": true,
            "path": "cache.appcache"
          }
        },
        "loader": {
          "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
        },
        "cache": {
          "enable": true
        },
        "compressor": {
          "type": "yui"
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Charts doesn't come with Community Edition version. if you still want to use you would need premium addons which you could download from support portal and copy the chart package in your package list.

Once done, you would need to include it in the app.json file of the application
requires : ['chart']

Then you would need to put the chart class which you are using in the requires config of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i downloaded charts with npm from sencha and its working fine in testbuild (so i already added it to app,json required), but i just cant build for production